# Replace switch cases to reduce complexity

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I wanted to replace switch cases with some other logic since it increases code complexity (CCN) on sonar.

```
enum ItemType {
    case one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten
}
```

```
func handleNavigation(itemType: ItemType){
    switch itemType {
    case .one:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: StoryboardSegue.One, sender: nil)
    case .two:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: StoryboardSegue.Two, sender: nil)
    case .three:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: StoryboardSegue.Three, sender: nil)
    case .four:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: StoryboardSegue.Four, sender: nil)
    case .five:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: StoryboardSegue.Five, sender: nil)
    case .six:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: StoryboardSegue.Six, sender: nil)
    case .seven:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: StoryboardSegue.Seven, sender: nil)
    case .eight:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: StoryboardSegue.Eight, sender: nil)
    case .nine:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: StoryboardSegue.Nine, sender: nil)
    case .ten:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: StoryboardSegue.Ten, sender: nil)
    }
}
```

We have to avoid this switch case since it increases CCN when number of cases increase.

How can we replace switch cases with other logic?

Comment: Can you show what the values for `StoryboardSegue.One`, `StoryboardSegue.Two`, etc are?

Comment: One  and two are storyboard identificier Strings as an example I kept as one and two here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the named constants in `StoryboardSegue`. Use the enum raw value instead.

First, give `ItemType` raw values by adding `: String`

```
enum ItemType: String {
    case one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten
}
```

Now you can do:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: itemType.rawValue, sender: nil)
```

This will perform segues with identifiers "one", "two", "three" etc.

If your segue identifiers have slightly different identifiers from the names of the enum cases, you can write a transformation function. For example, if they all end with "Segue".

```
func segueIdentifier(for itemType: ItemType) {
    itemType.rawValue + "Segue"
}

// ...

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifier(for: itemType), sender: nil)
```

If the identifiers are completely different from the enum case names, then you can use a dictionary:

```
enum ItemType: Hashable {
    case one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten
}

let segueIdMapping: [ItemType: _] = [
    .one: StoryboardSegue.One,
    .two: StoryboardSegue.Two,
    .three: StoryboardSegue.Three,
    // and so on
]

// ...

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdMapping[itemType]!, sender: nil)
```